# VS2019 Test Explorer not running tests for netcoreapp3.1 project using specflow+runner

Tags: visual-studio-2019, specflow, netcoreapp3.1

Example repo here - https://github.com/venkatrao-rgare/specflow-vs2019/
After I do clean and build the test are generated in test explorer, when I try to right click on the test and run, it fails.

I looked at the "TestResults" folder to see this in the log, I don't have `dotnet.exe`in `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\`, not sure where to find it.

Can someone help with this? What should I install / configure to make this test run as expected ?

````
2020-02-04T12:34:26.0176209-06:00:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.OutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsOutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan Zivkovic - It turned out to be an issue with Processor architecture. I posted this as a bug with Specflow not knowing if it was related to VS2019 or Specflow - the fix suggested in the comment in the bug to change the Processor architecture fixed it for me locally. - https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1877

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have this references in your project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.1.82" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.1.82" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.Runner" Version="3.1.48" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.SpecFlow" Version="3.1.48" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Please do remove references for `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` and `Newtonsoft.Json`, and then run test.

Comment: I posted an answer expecting it to be displayed underneath your answer but somehow it displayed before yours. Please see above.